# differences between for...in and for... , .. in

Tags: python

can anyone help me to figure out difference between

```
for abc in xyz
```

and

```
for abc, n in xyz
```

I know in first case each letter is assigned to abc in every iteration. How is it different from 2nd case

Comment: Okay i edited the question

Comment: What is `xyz`? A list, a dict, ...?

Answer (score 2):

```
xyz=[(3,8),(23,13),(89,34)]
for abc, n in xyz: print( abc, " ## ",n)
```

Result:

```
3  ##  8
23  ##  13
89  ##  34
```

Answer (score 1):

At first both lines are missing the `:` at the end.

The first iterates over the string `'xyz'`. This will do one iteration per character.
The second iterates over the variable `xyz`. This could be anything, so nothing can be said about the resulting iteration.

The first version assigns the item to the variable `abc`. The second required the item (per iteration) to be a pair, like a 2-tuple. The first value will be assigned to `abc`, the other to `n`. An example:

```
for i, character in enumerate('abc'):
    print(i, character)
```

Result:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Comment: The question has been edited. Now `xyz` is a variable in both cases.

Comment: @Aakash Then please answer this: What is `xyz`? A string, a list, a dict? What are the members?

Answer (score 0):

This is doing "tuple-unpacking" in a loop. What is tuple unpacking?

```
>>> t = ("foo", "bar")
>>> a, b = t
>>> a
'foo'
>>> b
'bar'
```

This will only work if the tuple has the same number of elements as there are variables you are unpacking it into. If you have a list (or generator) of tuples, you can do the same in a loop.

Some examples:

```
>>> for a, b in zip("abc", "123"):
...     print(a, b)
... 
('a', '1')
('b', '2')
('c', '3')
>>> for i, e in enumerate("abc"):
...     print(i, e)
... 
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `for abc, n in xyz` will unpack two elements from xyz, for example if you have a list of lists such as `xyz=[[1,2],[3,4]]` for each iteration you will get the elements from the inner list. However, if you had `xyz[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and you try to do `for abc, n in xyz`, you will get an error, as there are three elements to unpack, then you should do `for abc, n, a in xyz`.

If you do `for abc in xyz` then you will get each inner list (but not their elements for separated). Just try these examples:

```
xyz=[[1,2],[3,4]]
for abc in xyz:
   print abc

for abc, n in xyz:
  print "first element", abc
  print "second element", n

xyz = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

# in this case you will get an error
for abc, n in xyz:
  print "first element", abc
  print "second element", n

# this one will work
for abc, n, a in xyz:
   print "first element", abc
   print "second element", n
   print "third element", a
```